# Child module cannot find parrent static resources

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-4

I am use **spring boot + thymeleaf + spring4 + gradle** and build next project structure:

```
--- Root
src/main/resources/templates/common-part.html
--- First-child
src/main/resources/templates/first-child.html
--- Second-child 
src/main/resources/templates/second-child.html
```

When i build First-child project in the `build/resources/main/templates/` i have only `first-child.html` but i want also have `common-part.html` from parent.

How can i share static resources of root to my childs ?

Comment: I think this question more about `gradle` than about other tags.